# How can I check available RAM in my ionic 3 app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im using [extended-device-information](https://github.com/danielehrhardt/cordova-plugin-extended-device-information) plugin to get my mobile ram in ionic 3 application. But I would like to get available memory(RAM) in my device.
How to calculate available RAM in ionic 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**chrome.system.memory Plugin**

> It doesn't appear the `extended-device-information` plug-in can
>   calculate the "available memory". You would likely need to use the
>   [`chrome.system.memory Plugin`](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-memory) or similar to accomplish that.

↳ https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_memory

**extended-device-information Plugin**

From the documentation (only shows total memory capacity):

```
import { ExtendedDeviceInformation } from '@ionic-native/extended-device-information/ngx';

constructor(private extendedDeviceInformation: ExtendedDeviceInformation) { }

...

console.log('The Memory is: ' + this.extendedDeviceInformation.memory);
```

↳ https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/extended-device-information

Comment: It will return total RAM of the mobile. I want available RAM. Ex: 3 GB available for 8 GB

Comment: @SuryaTeja: It doesn't appear the plugin shows that information. You'd probably need to use something such as [this](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-chrome-apps-system-memory), which shows "available memory" in addition to total "capacity".